# How to run some cells in .ipynb with terminal commands?

Tags: python, terminal, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run some specific cells(e.g. cell 2 and 3) of a .ipynb document in terminal but find no way to do so.The existing solutions are about how to run a whole .ipynb document in terminal but not specific cells. Many thanks.